# how to get only the email address using php?

Tags: php, regex

can you please how to do this in php...

how to get only the **test@gmail.com**...

```
Username <testmail@gmail.com>
```

into

```
testmail@gmail.com
```

the Username and <> is deleted...

Comment: i have not tried anything sir... im trying to use substr????

Comment: You can use substring methods to get the text between `<` and `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you can use the `substr` function like this:

```
$string = 'Username <testmail@gmail.com>';
$opening = strpos($string, '<')+1;
$closing = strpos($string, '>');  
echo substr($string, $opening, $closing-$opening);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses are actually quit complex beasts.

You can keep it simple if your subject text is nothing fancy.

**Simple approach**

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

- Use this version to seek out email addresses in random documents and texts.
- Does not match email addresses using an IP address instead of a domain name.
- Does not match email addresses on new-fangled top-level domains with more than 4 letters such as .museum.  Including these increases the risk of false positives when applying the regex to random documents.
- Requires the "case insensitive" option to be ON.

**Email addresses according to RFC 2822**

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

This regular expression implements the official RFC 2822 standard for email addresses.  Using this regular expression in actual applications is NOT recommended.  It is shown to illustrate that with regular expressions there's always a trade-off between what's exact and what's practical.

**Note** Both of this regexes come out of the library of RegexBuddy

Answer (score 0):

One quick way without the usual precautions would be to use the following function:

```
function _stringExtractEmail( $x ) {

    return( substr( $x , strpos( $x , '<' ) + 1 , -1 ) ) ;

}

// Example
print( _stringExtractEmail( 'Zafar Iqbal <mail@zaf.io>' ) ) ;
```

Note the '-1' in the substr function , it just chops the last character, whatever it may be.